# PHPUnit CLI not available after PEAR install

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, pear

I've installed PHPUnit on my OS X Snow Leopard box using the following command:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

I would expect that the `phpunit`CLI command would be available after that, but it isn't. I've looked in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit` but can't find anything that looks like a CLI.

Can anyone tell me how to get the CLI up and running?

Comment: Where is your PHP binary located ? probably is at the same folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, after checking [installation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) page and running below commands, it started working. Just make sure to remove it before running them.

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, I received no errors after the pear installation, but some directories and files where installed (under /usr/lib/php/pear) and others missing (I had no phpunit.sh file among others).

My setup: OSX Lion 10.7.2 + PHP 5.3.6 + PEAR 1.9.2.

I can't really say for sure what the problem was, but I found that the PEAR installer was not up to date, so I upgraded it (to 1.9.4) with:

```
sudo pear upgrade pear
```

After that, following the phpunit manual, I typed:

```
sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
```

So yo don't need to add the channels for every package and dependency. And then:

```
sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

And voilà, everything is working finally!

Comment: Thanks so much! Spent hours on this and your solution worked right away.

Comment: This worked on CentOS when David Kuridza's solution did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to clear the cache after discovering the channels:

```
sudo pear clear-cache
```

I couldn't install anything with PEAR and clearing the cache worked for me